# С++ Qt Creator, error D8021 /Wno-reorder

Tags: c++, qt, visual-studio-2015

При попытке сборки программы([GitHub](https://github.com/victorprogrammist/forecasting_ver_001)) возникает несколько одинаковых ошибок

> cl : Command line error D8021 : invalid numeric argument '/Wno-reorder'

В .pro файле указанно

> QMAKE_CXXFLAGS_WARN_ON += -Wno-reorder

Искал в интернете, но проблем именно с Wno-reorder не находил.

Лог консоли сборки

```css
14:18:38: Выполняются этапы для проекта forecasting_ver_1...
14:18:38: Настройки не изменились, этап qmake пропускается.
14:18:38: Запускается: «C:\Qt\Tools\QtCreator\bin\jom.exe» 
 C:\Qt\Tools\QtCreator\bin\jom.exe -f Makefile.Debug
 cl -c -nologo -Zc:wchar_t -FS -Zc:rvalueCast -Zc:inline -Zc:strictStrings -Zc:throwingNew -Zi -MDd -W3 -w34100 -w34189 -w44996 -w44456 -w44457 -w44458 -wd4577 -wd4467 -Wno-reorder -EHsc /Fddebug\forecasting_ver_1.vc.pdb -DUNICODE -D_UNICODE -DWIN32 -D_ENABLE_EXTENDED_ALIGNED_STORAGE -DWIN64 -DQT_DEPRECATED_WARNINGS -DQT_QML_DEBUG -DQT_WIDGETS_LIB -DQT_GUI_LIB -DQT_CORE_LIB -I..\sources -I. -IC:\Qt\5.12.3\msvc2015_64\include -IC:\Qt\5.12.3\msvc2015_64\include\QtWidgets -IC:\Qt\5.12.3\msvc2015_64\include\QtGui -IC:\Qt\5.12.3\msvc2015_64\include\QtANGLE -IC:\Qt\5.12.3\msvc2015_64\include\QtCore -Idebug -I. -IC:\VulkanSDK\1.0.51.0\include -IC:\Qt\5.12.3\msvc2015_64\mkspecs\win32-msvc -Fodebug\ @C:\Users\Broness\AppData\Local\Temp\main.obj.6124.47.jom
ОШИБКА cl : Command line error D8021 : invalid numeric argument '/Wno-reorder' 
ОШИБКА jom: D:\Other\Study\42\forecasting_ver_001-master\build-forecasting_ver_1-Desktop_Qt_5_12_3_MSVC2015_64bit-Debug\Makefile.Debug [debug\main.obj] Error 2
 cl -c -nologo -Zc:wchar_t -FS -Zc:rvalueCast -Zc:inline -Zc:strictStrings -Zc:throwingNew -Zi -MDd -W3 -w34100 -w34189 -w44996 -w44456 -w44457 -w44458 -wd4577 -wd4467 -Wno-reorder -EHsc /Fddebug\forecasting_ver_1.vc.pdb -DUNICODE -D_UNICODE -DWIN32 -D_ENABLE_EXTENDED_ALIGNED_STORAGE -DWIN64 -DQT_DEPRECATED_WARNINGS -DQT_QML_DEBUG -DQT_WIDGETS_LIB -DQT_GUI_LIB -DQT_CORE_LIB -I..\sources -I. -IC:\Qt\5.12.3\msvc2015_64\include -IC:\Qt\5.12.3\msvc2015_64\include\QtWidgets -IC:\Qt\5.12.3\msvc2015_64\include\QtGui -IC:\Qt\5.12.3\msvc2015_64\include\QtANGLE -IC:\Qt\5.12.3\msvc2015_64\include\QtCore -Idebug -I. -IC:\VulkanSDK\1.0.51.0\include -IC:\Qt\5.12.3\msvc2015_64\mkspecs\win32-msvc -Fodebug\ @C:\Users\Broness\AppData\Local\Temp\dispersion.obj.6124.63.jom
 cl -c -nologo -Zc:wchar_t -FS -Zc:rvalueCast -Zc:inline -Zc:strictStrings -Zc:throwingNew -Zi -MDd -W3 -w34100 -w34189 -w44996 -w44456 -w44457 -w44458 -wd4577 -wd4467 -Wno-reorder -EHsc /Fddebug\forecasting_ver_1.vc.pdb -DUNICODE -D_UNICODE -DWIN32 -D_ENABLE_EXTENDED_ALIGNED_STORAGE -DWIN64 -DQT_DEPRECATED_WARNINGS -DQT_QML_DEBUG -DQT_WIDGETS_LIB -DQT_GUI_LIB -DQT_CORE_LIB -I..\sources -I. -IC:\Qt\5.12.3\msvc2015_64\include -IC:\Qt\5.12.3\msvc2015_64\include\QtWidgets -IC:\Qt\5.12.3\msvc2015_64\include\QtGui -IC:\Qt\5.12.3\msvc2015_64\include\QtANGLE -IC:\Qt\5.12.3\msvc2015_64\include\QtCore -Idebug -I. -IC:\VulkanSDK\1.0.51.0\include -IC:\Qt\5.12.3\msvc2015_64\mkspecs\win32-msvc -Fodebug\ @C:\Users\Broness\AppData\Local\Temp\corr.obj.6124.63.jom
 cl -c -nologo -Zc:wchar_t -FS -Zc:rvalueCast -Zc:inline -Zc:strictStrings -Zc:throwingNew -Zi -MDd -W3 -w34100 -w34189 -w44996 -w44456 -w44457 -w44458 -wd4577 -wd4467 -Wno-reorder -EHsc /Fddebug\forecasting_ver_1.vc.pdb -DUNICODE -D_UNICODE -DWIN32 -D_ENABLE_EXTENDED_ALIGNED_STORAGE -DWIN64 -DQT_DEPRECATED_WARNINGS -DQT_QML_DEBUG -DQT_WIDGETS_LIB -DQT_GUI_LIB -DQT_CORE_LIB -I..\sources -I. -IC:\Qt\5.12.3\msvc2015_64\include -IC:\Qt\5.12.3\msvc2015_64\include\QtWidgets -IC:\Qt\5.12.3\msvc2015_64\include\QtGui -IC:\Qt\5.12.3\msvc2015_64\include\QtANGLE -IC:\Qt\5.12.3\msvc2015_64\include\QtCore -Idebug -I. -IC:\VulkanSDK\1.0.51.0\include -IC:\Qt\5.12.3\msvc2015_64\mkspecs\win32-msvc -Fodebug\ @C:\Users\Broness\AppData\Local\Temp\f_auxiliary.obj.6124.63.jom
ОШИБКА cl : Command line error D8021 : invalid numeric argument '/Wno-reorder'
ОШИБКА cl : Command line error D8021 : invalid numeric argument '/Wno-reorder'
ОШИБКА jom: D:\Other\Study\42\forecasting_ver_001-master\build-forecasting_ver_1-Desktop_Qt_5_12_3_MSVC2015_64bit-Debug\Makefile.Debug [debug\dispersion.obj] Error 2
ОШИБКА jom: D:\Other\Study\42\forecasting_ver_001-master\build-forecasting_ver_1-Desktop_Qt_5_12_3_MSVC2015_64bit-Debug\Makefile.Debug [debug\corr.obj] Error 2
ОШИБКА cl : Command line error D8021 : invalid numeric argument '/Wno-reorder'
ОШИБКА jom: D:\Other\Study\42\forecasting_ver_001-master\build-forecasting_ver_1-Desktop_Qt_5_12_3_MSVC2015_64bit-Debug\Makefile.Debug [debug\f_auxiliary.obj] Error 2
ОШИБКА jom: D:\Other\Study\42\forecasting_ver_001-master\build-forecasting_ver_1-Desktop_Qt_5_12_3_MSVC2015_64bit-Debug\Makefile [debug] Error 2
14:18:38: Процесс «C:\Qt\Tools\QtCreator\bin\jom.exe» завершился с кодом 2.
Ошибка при сборке/установке проекта forecasting_ver_1 (комплект: Desktop Qt 5.12.3 MSVC2015 64bit)
Во время выполнения этапа «Сборка»
14:18:38: Прошло времени: 00:01.
```

Comment: ну уберите эту строчку и все, в студии нет такого аргумента

Comment: (facepalm) Помогло! Чувствую себя на уровне "Включите вилку в розетку". Спасибо.